# How do you access the current properties of an OwlCarousel?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I need to get the current number of items shown in an OwlCarousel. eg: the number that is set with the `{items: n}` setting. In this case using the responsive directive.

```
{
  items: 4,
  responsive: {
     720: {
         items: 3
     },
     320: {
         items: 2
     }
  }
}
```

Something like this I expect

```
var owl = $('.carousel').data('owl.carousel');
var current_items = owl.settings.items;
```

I would like to programmatically determine how many items are currently being shown at once.

Comment: which owl carousel are you using? version 1.x or 2?

Comment: Version 2 (as per the tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok looks like this is quite straight forward after all. You can also watch for properties changing (as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022311/owl-carousel-2-get-src-of-current-slide)). Looks like I just had the `.data()` selector incorrect.

```
// Grab your carousel
var carousel = $('.carousel').data('owlCarousel');
var current_items;
// Check that it already exists
if ( carousel ) {
  // Access it's settings property - "items" is updated 
  // when the breakpoint changes
  current_items = carousel.settings.items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below to get the number of active items

```
$('.owl-carousel .owl-item.active').length
```

Comment: That looks good in answering my specific case (current items) but not the question posed by the title (current properties) which can be accessed directly via settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can get by this :

```
   var totalItems = $('.owl-item.active').length;

   alert(totalItems);
```

Comment: That would be all the items in the carousel not the number shown I think. And is the `.item` class correct for version two?