# jQuery onChange function affects all sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I only want to add "fadeInLeft" class to the next carousel item's caption(h1 tag) but not the other h1 tags from its items' siblings as well as remove the class if it exist to be able to see the fadeInLeft effects when slide.

**So this is my jQuery function:**

```
function onChange() {
var el = $('.owl-carousel h1');
if ((el).is('.animated.fadeInLeft')) {
    el.removeClass('fadeInLeft')
        .addClass('fadeInLeft');
} else {
    el.addClass('fadeInLeft');
  }
}

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   onChange: onChange,
   items: 1,
   loop: true,
   nav: true,
   pagination: true
});
```

**And this is the content:**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item item1">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft">Some Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item item2">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="animated">Some Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item item3">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="animated">Some Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and [owl-carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/) plugin.

Please help me and thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: How is `onChange()` being called? Why is your selector so inclusive?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that, please see the changes/edit.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var e1 = $(this).find('h1');
```

instead of

```
var el = $('h1');
```

Comment: It doesn't add the class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
 var el = $('.yourclass h1').first();
```

**Or :**

```
var el = $('.yourclass h1').next(); if you really meant the next one
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.currentItem` to find current item and the use `next()` to find the next item, then find `h1` and do your success code...

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   onChange: function (elem) {
              var current = this.currentItem;
              var el = elem.find(".owl-carousel").eq(current).next().find('h1');
              if ((el).is('.animated.fadeInLeft')) {
                    el.removeClass('fadeInLeft')
                        .addClass('fadeInLeft');
                } else {
                    el.addClass('fadeInLeft');
                  }
                }
            },
   items: 1,
   loop: true,
   nav: true,
   pagination: true
});
```

Comment: I think it's almost there because this is much similar from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022311/owl-carousel-2-get-src-of-current-slide) . I got it working from that post but the function stops when the sliders end, meaning it doesn't repeat when all the items end. So the fadeInLeft class is always there.

And yours has an error on the line of declaring the _variable_ **el**.

Answer (score 0):

### This solved my issues

```
var slider = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  pagination: true
});

slider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
  var current = property.item.index;
  var el = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find("h1");

  var elPrev = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).prev().find("h1");
  var elNext = $(property.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).next().find("h1");

  elPrev.removeClass('fadeIn');
  elNext.removeClass('fadeIn');

  if (!(el).is('.fadeIn')) {
      el.addClass('fadeIn');
    }
  });
```

I should have read more the [documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html).
Anyway thanks for the help guys! You gave me some ideas. :)