# Make center image more bigger than the other in Owl Carousel js

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I want to make image in the center item more bigger or larger than the rest items visible. I am using Owl Carousel js.

See below screenshot on how it looks like.

[image]

This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kwowkfuy/, make `item` at the center bigger.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Provide some code. read this: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ah okay I will update my question

Comment: What have you tried? You can add a :hover pseudoclass class with `transform: scale(2, 2);` to make it bigger. Maybe check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/clarklab/pen/ByWjxy?page=1&)

Comment: @bellabelle I'm not sure but i believe you need something that detects wich image is in the center of the screen. As i am not that advanced into javascript I can only try to help by googleling stuff :)

Comment: @bellabelle Im not sure if K. Gkinis's awnser is what you are looking for but that code can of course be copied over and adjusted to your liking.

Comment: Yes @Granny you're right, I want to detect the center image then thats the time i can add the `transform scale`

Comment: please help, I'm still searching some relevant from google

Comment: @bellabelle How abou [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022311/owl-carousel-2-get-src-of-current-slide) if you can get the current source you can add a css style to that slide that adds the `transformscale`?

Comment: @Granny, it's not working

Comment: @bellabelle What is not working? I believe that question i linked is in Jquery so some pieces of code wont work but you can look for Javascript alternatives.

Comment: @Granny thank you for the help, I found the answer, I just need the updated version of owl carousel so I can call the active class of the center item.

Comment: @bellabelle Goodjob :) Glad you found the solution :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

Make `center: true` in owlCarousel configuration.

Now the `center` class will automatically be added to the centered item.

You can set CSS properties to make bigger.

```
.owl-item.active.center {
       transform: scale(1.1, 1.2);
 }
```

Comment: Sadly not satisfying enough for my needs. This way the element doesn't take up more space and you can't have equal spacing between all of the items.

Answer (score 0):

Add Center true in owl configuration settings

However this will mess with spacing between elements, Hence also add in your css.

`owl-item.center { display: block }`